# Neighbourhood graph of a given source in netwokx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using Networkx in python to play around with graphs.

I have a graph of about 1800 nodes.

What I want to implement is that given a source node , I want to be able to draw it's neighbourhood graph. If S is a source node,it's neighbourhood graph should contain (1) parents of S (2) Children of S (3) Siblings of S

I am able to get 1 and 2 through .predecessor and .successor respectively.

Is there a direct and elegant way to find 3 ? Going through all the children of the parents of source node is a cumbersome method.

Or even a direct function to build such a neighbourhood graph?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Note that what you describe is not a [neighborhood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)). Is there another name for what you're suggesting?

Comment: Can you give a (smaller) example graph where we see how relashionships are formed (e.g. by directed edges)?

Comment: Do you want a function that only performs this in selected cases, or to produce the sibling relationships for all nodes in the graph?  For the former, it is not obvious how else to compute sibling(x): child(Parent(x)) !=x in another way than to use the .predecessor function (at least under the hood somewhere)